# Can we migrate around 250 TB of files from file shares to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, limitations, storage, boundaries

I am working with a client who have 10 network drives each of average size of 25 TB . so now we want to migrate all those files from the file Shares to SharePoint online, so can we migrate around 250 TB of data to SharePoint online?

**Currently we are planning to upload all the data to a single site collection, and we are planning to use the Microsoft migration tool**

[image]

So will this work? or we will face issues since we are going to migrate 250 TB to a single site collection? and if this will not work, then is there any workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Single Site Collections can only be up to 25TB. In addition, 250TB of storage likely exceeds your tenant quota unless you have a significant number of licensed users -- you can purchase more storage from Microsoft. You can see your overall quota in the SharePoint Online admin center.

Comment: when i access SharePoint admin center i got that i have `1.99 TB available of 2.00 TB`.. so does this mean that our tenant can only have 2 TB ? Second question, so what we can do to store more than 25 TB for a single site? Thanks

Comment: third question, what is the relation between the number of users and storage quote for SharePoint?   i mean can not we purchase as much storage as we want regardless how many users we have?

Comment: You can purchase additional SPO storage as needed, though it is not necessarily cheap.

You cannot exceed 25TB content per site. That's a hard limit, for now.

Comment: ok thanks for the info.. so we can store the 250 TB inside SharePoint site this should not be an issue if we purchase the storage.. but the issue will be that we can not store more than 25 TB inside a single site collection,,, so the only option is to split the files over multiple site collections. am i correct?

Comment: second question,  how much we will have to pay to get 250 TB ? thanks

Comment: Correct, you need to split the content over multiple sites.

Comment: @CallumCrowley but how much will it cost me to get extra 248 TBs ? based on my reading that each 1 extra TB will cost 200USD per month, so in my case i have to pay (200 USD x 248 TBs) = 49,600 USD/ Month ?

Comment: I'm not sure, better off contacting a Microsoft sales representative.